# Trouble understanding the following pythonic snippet

Tags: python

I know this will return the original array s.t it has no leading zeroes but i don't understand how the syntax here enables that.

```
result = [0,0,1,4,2,0,3]
result = result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0),
                         len(result)):] or [0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down:

```
result = result[
    next(
       (i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0),
       len(result)
    ):
] or [0]
```

Python `next()` function takes first argument as iterator and second argument as default. Default is used when the iterator is "empty". So if the line of `i for i, x....` yields nothing, the result would be `result[len(result):]` or simply an empty string. In which case, the `or [0]` part takes action and returns you an one-element list `[0]`.

Now goes to the iterator line. It says

```
i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0
```

which in English means find all indices `i` of `result` such that `result[i] != 0`. And put it to `next()`, it means you take the first of such indices. So in the input list, you are extracting the *index* of the first element that is not zero. Then, using the same logic as the previous paragraph, you build `result[i:]`, which means taking the sub-list of `result` from the first non-zero element.

Comment: After reading your response I still don't quite understand how writing the code like this makes result = [0] if the original result consists of only 0'? For example if the list only contains 0's, then next() will return len(result). Thus we end up with result[len(result):] or [0]; equivalently [] or [0]. How does python know when to return the empty list or [0]?

Comment: @KaiLee `A or B` is a [shortcircuit notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Means if `A` is not a "true" value, it evaluates into `B`. In this case `[]` is "false" value in Python, so you will always have `[0]` back.

Comment: @KaiLee note that if the list only contains 0's, `result[len(result):]` is an empty list `[]`, not `[0]`. Here is where the `or` statement will finally assign `[0]` to `result`.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [0,0,1,4,2,0,3]
a = (i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0)
print(a)  # <generator object <genexpr> at 0x110e075e8>
b = next(a, len(result))
print(b)  # 2
c = result[b:]
print(c) # [1, 4, 2, 0, 3]
result = c or [0]
print(result) # [1, 4, 2, 0, 3]
```

Comment: This breakdown doesn't quite work, because `print(list(a))` uses up the generator, so `next(a, len(result))` won't give the intended result.

Comment: Other than that, I like this approach of showing all the steps, although you should add some explanation.

Comment: I should have cloned the generator using `itertools.tee` or something like that.

Comment: I didn't know you could clone generators like that

Answer (score 0):

```
enumerate(result)
```

produces an iterable similar to

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 2), (5, 0), (6, 3)]
```

`i for i, x` is saying for the first and second index, return the first. So we now have a list of 0-6.

`next()` takes this list as an iterator, and if the iterator doesn't yield anything, returns `[0]`, due to the `or` statement.

Basically, you're replacing the first element with `[0]` (which doesn't do anything), then copying the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0):

By all means, @adrtam and others have already explained it all very well. For those looking at an explanation with (ugly) code, it would looks something like this:

```
result = [0,0,1,4,2,0,3]

i=0                  # initialize the position counter
for x in result:     # scan each element in the list...
    if x != 0:       # ...checking for non-zero elements...
        break        # ... break the loop if we find it...
    else:
        i+=1         # ... otherwise increase the counter

# i is now the index of the first non-zero element in the list

result = result[i:]  # take a slice of the list, starting with the i-th element
                     # Note that, if i=len(result), then the slice will be an
                     # empty array []. That would happen, for example, if all
                     # the elements in the array were 0 (since we are checking
                     # against 0

# Hence the protection: 
# If we ended up here with an empty list, assign a list with a single 0 instead

if not result:  
    result = [0]

print(result)
```

See it in action here https://eval.in/1101785